# A-Frame WebVR - Device Orientation breaks

Tags: css, aframe, device-orientation

[image]When viewing this [Codepen Demo](https://s.codepen.io/officebook/debug/72d27d16129fba82ba73005906f59649) on a device on portrait, it works as expected.  When veiwing with device orientation lock off and turning to landscape, it fills half the screen.

**CODE**

```
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  </head>

<body>

  <a-scene>
    <a-sky src="https://ucarecdn.com/e1c757bc-73ee-4efe-b068-4f778ce212a3/" rotation="0 -20 0"></a-sky>
  </a-scene>

</body>

</html>
```

I've tried this meta tag with no success:

```
<meta http-equiv="ScreenOrientation" content="autoRotate:disabled">
```

**HERE"S MY PEN**

[Codepen Code](https://codepen.io/officebook/pen/72d27d16129fba82ba73005906f59649)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with the latest version of a-frame by chance?

`<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.0/aframe.min.js"></script>`

A quick test appears to work on my phone in both landscape and portrait:

https://a-frame-device-orientation-test.glitch.me/